# How do I setup my Ubuntu 12.04 PPTPD Server properly?

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-12.04, pptp

Ok so I have setup a PPTPD server and configured it appropriately.

**Here is my pptpd-options:**

```
name pptpd
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
debug
lock
nobsdcomp
```

**Here is my pptpd.conf:**

```
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
debug
logwtmp
localip 192.168.1.241
remoteip 192.168.1.234-238,192.168.1.245
```

**Here is my chap-secrets:**

```
username pptpd password  *
```

My problem is that when I turn on `require-mschap-v2` and\or `require-mppe-128` that the connection fails and produces the following error.

```
Dec 27 16:18:51 mmweb1 pppd[3252]: Plugin /usr/lib/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Dec 27 16:18:51 mmweb1 pppd[3252]: pptpd-logwtmp: $Version$
Dec 27 16:18:51 mmweb1 pptpd[3251]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=6075a0,len=8196) from PTY 
failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected
termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Dec 27 16:18:51 mmweb1 pptpd[3251]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
Dec 27 16:18:51 mmweb1 pptpd[3251]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[3252]
Dec 27 16:18:51 mmweb1 pptpd[3251]: CTRL: Client 192.168.1.240 control connection 
finished
Dec 27 16:18:51 mmweb1 pptpd[3251]: CTRL: Exiting now
Dec 27 16:18:51 mmweb1 pptpd[3075]: MGR: Reaped child 3251
```

If I turn off `require-mschap-v2` and `require-mppe-128` I produce the following results and the connection succeeds and starts accepting packets.

```
Dec 27 16:30:18 mmweb1 pppd[3314]: Plugin /usr/lib/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Dec 27 16:30:18 mmweb1 pppd[3314]: pptpd-logwtmp: $Version$
Dec 27 16:30:18 mmweb1 pptpd[3313]: GRE: Bad checksum from pppd.
Dec 27 16:30:18 mmweb1 pptpd[3313]: CTRL: Received PPTP Control Message (type: 15)
Dec 27 16:30:18 mmweb1 pptpd[3313]: CTRL: Got a SET LINK INFO packet with standard ACCMs
```

What I notice is that it always says that GRE: Bad checksum from pppd. It makes me wonder what exactly is messed up with GRE on the server. Please note that I am able to connection with encryption turned off so I don't think that it is my router or isp or anything else like that. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Hi, i wonder if you got the solution. If yes, please share the solution.